# How to disable a radio button if the other one is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to disable a radio button if the other one is selected.

Next to the radio input is a text input in which if they choose the option, they would write the age depending on the selection of the radio (months or years).

Ideally, the text input would be disabled too. I have this code right now but it's not working:

```
<div class="md-form mb-3">
    <i class="fas fa-paw prefix grey-text"></i><label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" style="padding-left: 5px">Age: </label>
    <br />
    <input type="radio"  id="age_in_years" name="age_in_years" value="years">
    <label for="age_in_years">Años:</label><input id="age_in_years"type="number" name="age_in_years" ng-model="age_in_years" class="form-control" style="margin-left: 5px;width: 70px;"/>
    <input type="radio"  id="age_in_months" name="age_in_months" value="months">
    <label for="age_in_months">Months:</label><input id="age_in_months" type="number" name="age_in_months" value="age_in_months" ng-model="age_in_months" class="form-control" style="margin-left: 5px;width:70px;"/>
</div>


<script>
    function selection() {
        let x = document.getElementById("age_in_years");
        let y = document.getElementById("age_in_months");

        if (x.checked()) {
            document.getElementById("age_in_months").disabled = true;
        }
        else if (y.checked()) {
            document.getElementById("age_in_years").disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: first .. Its `checked` Not `checked()`

Comment: To be clear: if the user selects "months" then they can no longer select "years"?  What if they accidently pick the wrong one or change their mind?

Comment: you have duplicate IDs - they **must** be unique

Comment: Yeah sorry it was a typo, meant for "disabled"

Comment: A pure HTML-solution is to give them the same `name=""` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor the HTML slightly and generate the radio buttons with the same name so that only 1 can ever be checked at a time. With that in place some simple javascript to determine the other inputs can be used to disable the number input.

`label` elements should not be used for arbitrary HTML - they are to be associated with input elements ( either using for=ID syntax or by wrapping the input element itself ) - hence some alterations to the markup.

```js
document.addEventListener('change',e=>{
  if( e.target.name=='age_unit' ){
    let parent=e.target.parentNode;
    
    let self=parent.querySelector(`input[type='number'][name='age[${e.target.value}]']`);
    let other=parent.querySelector(`input[type='number']:not( [name='age[${e.target.value}]'] )`);
    
    self.disabled=false;
    other.disabled=true;
    
    self.required=true;
    other.required=false;
    
    self.focus();
  }
})
```

```css
[type='number']{
  width:70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="md-form mb-3">
  <i class="fas fa-paw prefix grey-text"></i>
  <h2>Age:</h2>


  <input type="radio" name="age_unit" value="years" />
  <label>Años:
   <input type="number" name="age[years]" ng-model="age_in_years" class="form-control" disabled />
  </label>



  <input type="radio" name="age_unit" value="months" />
  <label>Months:
    <input type="number" name="age[months]" ng-model="age_in_months" class="form-control" disabled />
  </label>


</div>
```

Comment: As an extra: I'd also add some UX to either: disable *both* inputs until radio selected or auto-select the radio when an input gets focus.

Comment: that would be easy enough - just tweak the html and add the disabled attribute should do it

Comment: You are welcome - glad that it helped solve your conundrum

Answer (score 1):

A radio type is grouped by the name, so using the same name would already give the behavior you want, without needing any JavaScript.

```html
<div class="md-form mb-3">
  <i class="fas fa-paw prefix grey-text"></i>
  <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" style="padding-left: 5px">Age: </label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" id="age_in_years" name="age" value="years">
  <label for="age_in_years">Años:</label><input id="age_in_years"type="number" name="age_in_years" ng-model="age_in_years" class="form-control" style="margin-left: 5px;width: 70px;"/>
  <input type="radio"  id="age_in_months" name="age" value="months">
  <label for="age_in_months">Months:</label>
  <input id="age_in_months" type="number" name="age_in_months" value="age_in_months" ng-model="age_in_months" class="form-control" style="margin-left: 5px;width:70px;"/>
</div>
```

This would make sure that if one of radio elements is clicked or, once another one is clicked, the previous would be unchecked.

Because you have a `value` there, there's no reason to use different names, because the value already hints what kind of data has been submitted or is required.